# Displaying data from an ISP/Telephone (Telstra.com.au in Australia)

Tags: java, soap, axis, yodlee

I am currently having issues in attempting to display data (i.e. `itemSummaries` with a certain `ContainerType`) for sites that are ISP, as an example, www.telstra.com.au from Australia

Logging into the site works fine, and the credentials for the site work fine (in other words, it does a refresh which succeeds), however there doesn't appear to be a way to display the `itemSummary` data

The `soap` command `getItemSummaries`, doesn't display data for the item (it displays item data from financial institutions fine). Upon examining the sample code provided by `Yodlee` for the java soap api, you are meant to use the `getItemSummaries1` along with setting `ContainerTypes` using a `SummaryRequest`

The problem is that this returns a `CoreExceptionFaultMessage`. The `getItemSummaries1` command is causing the `CoreExceptionFaultError`. Using different `ContainerTypes` with different combinations (i.e. `ISP`, `Telephone`, `Bills`) didn't alleviate the issue

The same error message is returned in `Yodlees` own sample code, i.e. java_soap_example (run the `com.yodlee.sampleapps.accountsummary.DisplayBillsData` main method and provide the Yodlee login info as command line arguments)

As a reference, the code that is provided by Yodlee sample app is below

**Running the getItemSummaries1 command**

```
public void displayBillsData (UserContext userContext)
{
    /*SummaryRequest sr = new SummaryRequest(
            new String[] {ContainerTypes.BILL, ContainerTypes.TELEPHONE},
            new DataExtent[] { DataExtent.getDataExtentForAllLevels(),DataExtent.getDataExtentForAllLevels() }
    );*/
    SummaryRequest sr = new SummaryRequest();
    List list = new List();
    list.setElements(new String[] {ContainerTypesHelper.BILL, ContainerTypesHelper.TELEPHONE});
    sr.setContainerCriteria(list);

    Object[] itemSummaries = null;
    List itemSummariesList = null;
    try {
        itemSummariesList = dataService.getItemSummaries1(userContext, sr);
        if (itemSummariesList != null){
            itemSummaries = itemSummariesList.getElements();
        }
    } catch (StaleConversationCredentialsExceptionFault e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidConversationCredentialsExceptionFault e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CoreExceptionFault e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentTypeExceptionFault e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentValueExceptionFault e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidUserContextExceptionFault e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalDataExtentExceptionFault e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (itemSummaries == null || itemSummaries.length == 0) {
        System.out.println ("No bills data available");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < itemSummaries.length; i++) {
        ItemSummary is = (ItemSummary) itemSummaries[i];
        displayBillsDataForItem(is);

        // Dump the BillsData Object
        // dumpBillsDataForItem(is);
    }
}
```

**Printing the item data**

```
public void displayBillsDataForItem (ItemSummary is)
    {
        String containerType = is.getContentServiceInfo ().
                getContainerInfo ().getContainerName ();

        System.out.println("containerType = " + containerType );

        if (!(containerType.equals(ContainerTypesHelper.BILL ) || containerType.equals(ContainerTypesHelper.TELEPHONE) 
                || containerType.equals(ContainerTypesHelper.MINUTES))) {
            throw new RuntimeException ("displayBillsDataForItem called with " +
                    "invalid container type: " + containerType);
        }


        DisplayItemInfo displayItemInfo = new DisplayItemInfo ();
        System.out.println("DisplayItemInfo:");
        displayItemInfo.displayItemSummaryInfo (is);
        System.out.println("");
        ItemData id = is.getItemData();

        if(id == null){
           System.out.println("ItemData == null");
        }else{
            List accountsList = id.getAccounts();
            Object[] accounts = null;
            if (accountsList != null){
                accounts = accountsList.getElements();
            }
            if (accounts == null || accounts.length == 0) {
                System.out.println ("\tNo accounts");
            }else {
                for (int accts = 0; accts < accounts.length; accts++) {
                    BillsData billsData = (BillsData) accounts[accts];
                    System.out.println("\tAccount Holder: " + billsData.getAccountHolder() );
                    System.out.println("\tAccount Id: " + billsData.getAccountId());
                    System.out.println("\tItemAccountId: " + billsData.getItemAccountId() );
                    System.out.println("\tAccountName: " + billsData.getAccountName() );
                    System.out.println("\tAccountNumber: " + billsData.getAccountNumber() );
                    System.out.println("");

                    // Get List of Bill Objects
                    List billsList = billsData.getBills();
                    Object[] bills = null;
                    if (billsList != null){
                        bills = billsList.getElements();
                    }
                    if (bills == null || bills.length == 0) {
                        System.out.println ("\t\tNo Bill objects");
                    }else {
                        for (int b = 0; b < bills.length; b++) {
                            Bill bill = (Bill) bills[b];
                            System.out.println("\t\tBill Account Number: " + bill.getAccountNumber() );
                            System.out.println("\t\tBill Acct Type: " + bill.getAcctType() );
                            System.out.println("\t\tBill Due Date: " + Formatter.formatDate(bill.getDueDate().getDate(), Formatter.DATE_SHORT_FORMAT) );
                            System.out.println("\t\tBill Date: " + Formatter.formatDate(bill.getBillDate().getDate(), Formatter.DATE_SHORT_FORMAT) );
                            System.out.println("\t\tBill Past Due: "
                                    + (bill.getPastDue() != null ? bill
                                            .getPastDue().getAmount() : 0.0));
                            System.out
                                    .println("\t\tBill Last payment: "
                                            + (bill.getLastPayment() != null ? bill
                                                    .getLastPayment()
                                                    .getAmount()
                                                    : 0.0));
                            System.out.println("\t\tBill Amount Due: "
                                    + (bill.getAmountDue() != null ? bill
                                            .getAmountDue().getAmount() : 0.0));
                            System.out
                                    .println("\t\tBill Min Payment: "
                                            + (bill.getMinPayment() != null ? bill
                                                    .getMinPayment()
                                                    .getAmount()
                                                    : 0.0));
                            System.out.println("");

                            // Get List of AccountUsageData
                            List acctUsageDataList = bill.getAccountUsages();
                            Object[] acctUsageData = null;
                            if (acctUsageDataList != null){
                                acctUsageData = acctUsageDataList.getElements();
                            }
                            if (acctUsageData == null || acctUsageData.length == 0) {
                                System.out.println ("\t\t\tNo AccountUsageData objects");
                            }else {
                                for (int usage = 0; usage < acctUsageData.length; usage++) {
                                    AccountUsageData aud = (AccountUsageData) acctUsageData[usage];
                                    System.out.println("\t\t\tAccount Usage Bill ID: " + aud.getBillId() );
                                    System.out.println("\t\t\tAccount Usage Units Used: " + aud.getUnitsUsed() );
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("");

                    // Get List of AccountUsageData
                    List acctUsageDataList = billsData.getAccountUsages();
                    Object[] acctUsageData = null;
                    if (acctUsageDataList != null){
                        acctUsageData = acctUsageDataList.getElements();
                    }
                    if (acctUsageData == null || acctUsageData.length == 0) {
                        System.out.println ("\t\tNo AccountUsageData objects");
                    }else {
                       for (int usageData = 0; usageData < acctUsageData.length; usageData++) {
                            AccountUsageData aud = (AccountUsageData) acctUsageData[usageData];
                            System.out.println("\t\tAccount Usage Bill ID: " + aud.getBillId() );
                            System.out.println("\t\tAccount Usage Units Used: " + aud.getUnitsUsed() );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT2:

I have updated the `getItemSummaries1` command to look like this

```
    ContainerCriteria bills = new ContainerCriteria();
    ContainerCriteria telephone = new ContainerCriteria();
    ContainerCriteria isp = new ContainerCriteria();
    ContainerCriteria utilities = new ContainerCriteria();
    bills.setContainerType(ContainerTypesHelper.BILL);
    telephone.setContainerType(ContainerTypesHelper.TELEPHONE);
    isp.setContainerType(ContainerTypesHelper.ISP);
    utilities.setContainerType(ContainerTypesHelper.UTILITIES);

    Object[] containerList = {
            bills,telephone,isp,utilities
    };

    SummaryRequest sr = new SummaryRequest();
    List list = new List();
    list.setElements(containerList);
    sr.setContainerCriteria(list);
```

The command now executes and works correctly, however its returning a list of 0 elements (using `DataExtents` with different values didn't change anything). My suspicion is that Telstra.com.au site is broken on Yodlee's end (when a full refresh is done on the Telstra site, Yodlee returns a null for refreshing that specific site).

Answer (score 0):

So far I can see some deviation, so do modify your container criteria as mentioned below

```
object[] list = {
    new ContainerCriteria { containerType = "bills" },
    new ContainerCriteria { containerType = "telephone" }
};

sr.containerCriteria = list;
```

You may additionally provide data extent as follows

```
DataExtent de = new DataExtent();
dataExtent.startLevel = 0; //as per your needs
dataExtent.endLevel = 0; //as per your needs

object[] list = {
    new ContainerCriteria { containerType = "bills", dataExtent = de },
    new ContainerCriteria { containerType = "telephone", dataExtent = de }
};

sr.containerCriteria = list;
```

This should solve your issue. If not then try to get the detail which is is node in the response for the `CoreExceptionFaultMessage`, this detail may help to diagnose the accurate issue.

Comment: The command now runs without Yodlee returning the `CoreExceptionFaultMessage`, however its not retrieving any data from the `getItemSummaries1` command (get a list that is 0 elements in length). As per my updated post, suspicion is that the yodlee's Telstra site is broken

Comment: `Telstra site is broken` that is quite possible as Yodlee do add or remove the sites for number of reasons. Also it might be temporary unavailable because of challenges to cope up with any recent implementation on the site. However Yodlee does make it's effort to notify the same. I too face similar issue when 2 of the banking service ids were no more valid and one of them was merged with another service for the purpose of single service id.

Answer (score 0):

To get data for any of the container first you need to add an account for the site belonging to that container. Once you have added the account successfully then only you will be able to pull in the data for such container. Also you can check the  tag returned in the getItemSummaries API which has  and once this statusCode = 0 then only you have data present for that account.

You can do testing by using the Dummy account which yodlee provides. Please refer to [Yodlee Dummy account generator](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Indy_FinApp_Knowledgebase/Sample_Data/Yodlee_Dummy_Account_Generator) page for more info on Dummy accounts.